# Component creation order in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-components

I'm trying to read a list of components and dynamically creating them on my page. I'm using ComponentResolver for this and creating the components using the new @ViewChild way.

I have a MainComponent file that extends a ComponentCreator class. This ComponentCreator class is a base class which all other components can 'extend' and use to create their respective child components.

Here are the code snippets to make things clearer:

**MainComponent.ts**

```
export class MainComponent extends ComponentCreator {

@ViewChild("target", { read: ViewContainerRef }) target;

constructor(_componentResolver: ComponentResolver, metaService: MetaService) {
    super(_componentResolver, metaService, "./src/app/meta.json", "MainComponent");
}
```

**ComponentCreator.ts**

```
export class ComponentCreator{

   //declare variables

   constructor(_componentResolver: ComponentResolver, _metaService: MetaService, _templateUrl: string, _templateName: string) {
    this._componentResolver = _componentResolver;
    this._templateUrl = _templateUrl;
    this._metaService = _metaService;
    this._templateName = _templateName;
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
  //metaService gets the template. It's a json file in which all the child components of Main component are listed
    this._metaService.getTemplate(this._templateUrl)
        .subscribe(
        _template => this._template = this.loadComponents(_template),
        error => this._errorMessage = <any>error);
   }

   loadChildComponents(template) {
    //Create components here
    //'place' comes from the json file. It's Equal to target.
    for(let component in jsonData)
         this._componentResolver.resolveComponent(component).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>)=> { this.cmpRef = this.place.createComponent(factory)});
   }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is in the order of component creation. For example, I have 4 child components of which 2 are plain HTML tables and 2 are some charts that are drawn using d3. Even though I'm specifying the creation order as 1,2,3,4 ; the order of rendering is messed up. As they all load inside the 'target' div, the HTML tables are rendered fast and come before both the charts.

Is there any way to fix it or will I have to use separate divs for tables and charts so that the order remains the same?

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates the issue? The code you provided doesn't use `target` anywhere and it's not obvious how you use d3. Therefore hard to reason about what's going on.

Comment: just create variables with priority and add *ngIf on components

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've edited my post to reflect the use of target. I'll try to create a plunker for it but it'd be great if you're able to gauge it using the new edit info. The order of HTML tables doesn't change and order of d3 graphs doesn't change among their respective categories. But they get messed up with each other.

Comment: @mayur sorry, I'm relatively new to angular 2. Can you provide an example that uses priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call async code within a `for()` loop which results in random order.

Use `Promise.all()` to ensure they are executed one after the other

```
Promise.all(
  jsonData.map(component => 
     this._componentResolver.resolveComponent(component)
     .then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>)=> { 
       this.cmpRef = this.place.createComponent(factory);
     });
  )
);
```

See also a similar example for the old `DynamicComponentLoader` at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7854#issuecomment-203988888

Comment: That might be correct. I just tried logging the component names and saw that they're coming in a different order than that specified in the json. I'll try to use Promise.all and tell you if this works! Thanks!